# Basic menu driven program C++, infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I've been creating a simple menu driven conversion program, but somehow created an infinite loop in one of the functions (the miles to km one) and don't know how to fix it.

The second function seems to work just fine.
Any advice or tips are very much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void showChoices();
double miles(double, double);
double degf(double, double);

int main ()
{
    double x, y;
    int choice;
    do
    {
        showChoices();
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "Input miles to be converted, enter * to submit: \n";
                cin >> x >> y;
                cout << x << " is " << miles(x,y) << " in kilometers" << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Input degrees (in Farenheit) to be converted, enter * to submit: \n";
                cin >> x >> y;
                cout << x << " is " << degf(x,y) << " in degrees Celsius" << endl;
                break;
        }
    }
    while (choice != 2);
    return 0;
}
void showChoices()
{
    cout << "MENU" << endl;
    cout << "1: Miles to Kilometers " << endl;
    cout << "2: Farenheit to Celsius " << endl;
}
double miles(double mi, double km)
{
    return km = mi * 1.609344;
}
double degf(double fah, double cel)
{
    return cel = 5*(fah-32)/9;
}
```

Comment: As already the bug been found out, I will suggest you to have "default" case, and may be you can add a field to check if you want to continue further, or not, a better way to control your loop.

Answer (score 3):

For choice is 1: while loop is always true and hence it goes in loop.

Add choice as 3: For exit.
Change the while condition to (choice != 3), which will break the loop.